# Java: Read Line From File Based on Start of Line

Tags: java, file, io

I know how to read from file using Java. What I want to do is read a specific line which starts with specific text.

What I plan on doing is storing certain program settings in a txt file so I can retrieve them quickly when I exit/restart program.

For example, the file may look something like this:

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Smith
Email: JohnSmith@gmail.com
Password: 123456789
```

The `:` would be the delimiter and in the program I want to be able to retrieve specific values based on the "key" (such as "First Name", "Last Name" and so on).

I know I could store it to DB but I want to write it quickly to test my program without going through hassle of writing it to DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)). It does everything you ask for here, including parsing the file.

example code:

```
    File file = new File("myprops.txt");
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream (file)) {
         properties.load (in);
    }

    String myValue = (String) properties.get("myKey");
    System.out.println (myValue);
```

Note: if you want to use a space in your property key, you have to escape it. For example:

```
First\ Name: Stef
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) is documentation about the syntax of the properties file.

Comment: it seems to be what I'm looking for but if you can provide a quick example based on link I would be able to verify and accept answer

Comment: @RonPall Start from official tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Comment: Do I need to store key/value pair using "Properties" object as when I store it manually and retrieve with this method it returns null (i.e, I enter "First Name" as key but it returns null..

Comment: it returns `null` if the key you're looking for is not in the map. Maybe you misspelled the key?

Comment: No.. I checked again. What I mean is I manually typed the words `"First Name: John"` into the text file and I am passing `"First Name: "` (and other variations) as key (to test) but it returns null..

Comment: ok I edited my answer... some characters (like space) need special handling to include in key name

Comment: yup, just figured it out seconds before you wrote this.. it works now! Accepted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is read a specific line which starts with specific text.

Read from the start of the file, skipping all the lines you don't need.  There is no simpler way.  You can index you file for fast access, but you have scan the file at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) to retrieve both key and value from file.
Reading data from text file using `Properties` class

```
            File file = new File("text.txt");
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();

            Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);//with specific key
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);//both key and value
            }
```

You can retrieve specific `value` based on the `key`.

```
   System.out.println(properties.getProperty("Password"));//with specific key
```

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can also read your file into a map this way:

```
        Map<String, String> propertiesMap = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.txt")) // read in to Stream<String>
            .map(x -> x.split(":\\s+")) // split to Stream<String[]> 
            .filter(x->x.length==2) // only accept values which consist of two values
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x[0], x -> x[1])); // create map. first element or array is key, second is value
```